# Invisible column in GridX?

Tags: dojo, dojo.gridx

Is it possible to create a column in **GridX** that will be invisible and not rendered? I don't want to simply hide cells with CSS because it's not elegant and it can have side effects.

Invisible columns are usefull, because for example, in `onApply` event from cell editor, I become a row data that contains only those fields from dataStore, that are declared as column.

Is there such feature in GridX as invisible column?

I'm using Dojo 1.9 with GridX 1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hidden columns module:

[gridx/modules/HiddenColumns (version 1.2)](http://oria.github.io/gridx/apidoc/index.html#1.2/gridx/modules/HiddenColumns)

Hide columns and change the column array at the same time so that other grid features are not affected by hidden columns. That means, hidden columns can no longer be accessed through grid.columns() function.

Answer (score 0):

Update -
I played around with the test GridX [here](http://evan.dojotoolkit.org/dojo-1.7rc1-gridx/gridx/tests/test_grid.html) and the least width it goes up to is 20px. However [this email](http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/gridx-column-style-td3994673.html) from one of the developers actually suggests that this might not be possible at all!

Earlier -
Have you tried building the grid with [ColumnResizer](http://oria.github.io/gridx/apidoc/index.html#1.2/gridx/modules/ColumnResizer) module, and, [selecting the required column](http://oria.github.io/gridx/apidoc/index.html#1.2/gridx/modules/select/Column), and, using the setWidth() method to set the width to zero? - this does NOT work.